# How to generate Hyperledger Fabric keystore offline

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using fabric-sdk-nodejs to enroll the user it works fine, but all the private key and msp will be created using fabric CA.

my questions

1. How i can generate keypair for offline user and then generate the certificate using fabric CA for particular organisation?
2. Is it possible to create keypair offline, which keypair generation is supported or fabric has own offline keypair generation?
3. In production environment we cannot keep the user keypair, so how generation of keypair flow works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to do is wrong

generation of private key and certificate is a multi-step procedure

When you try to create a keypair(private key & certificate) root-ca or intermediate-ca has to sign it then only it will be valid, this is called signing by using the concept of  PKI

Fabric supports x509 certificate & ecdsa private key, you can generate root-ca certificate and sign certs outside.

Coming to your question about security of user credentials: you can always use fabric-ca to generate the sign certs and you have three options

- store in the server as file-storage
- store it in couchdb as key-value store
- store it in hardware using hsm or so

Comment: In that case, User who want to register, their private key will be generated by farbic CA and stored in Fabric CA db?

Comment: Fabric-CA always has a dB to store identities but if your custome application needs private key and certificate of the user in order to authenticate then you need to store it somewhere

Comment: i am bit confused here, Assume org1 has fabric CA, Admin is already enrolled. Now if the user wants to register from outside the organisation, where does the user send the request to register and how user will get the certificate. secondly, If user want to send any transaction, do he need to sign with public key or certificate.

Comment: Seems like you have not finished the basic tutorials such as fabcar, In order to understand please finish the basic tutorials https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/write_first_app.html

Comment: thanks for repay,i checked the fabcar, it is same, its create the private key in hfc-key-store folder and copy of private key in wallet. In real world, if Admin add the new user, admin will have users password(security issue), and admin will give password to users to enroll. once the user is enroll,the private key created in server using fabric ca. It wont be security issue ?  or is any otherway to generate private key?

Comment: The flow is as follows: Org Admin will register a user and he will get secret then admin will give secret to the user in order to enroll. If both are using same application then you can do on behalf of them and store private keys in couch dB or hsm